# string.format(format,doubleValue) , precision lost

Tags: c#, double, string.format, double-precision

I have this `double` value:

```
var value = 52.30298270000003
```

and when I convert it to `string`, it losses its **precision**:

```
var str = string.Format("{0} some text...", value);
Console.WriteLine(str); // output: 52.3029827
```

The number of **precision** on my `double` value may be changed at run-time. How can I force the `string.Format` method to use all **precision**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `R` format specifier

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

> Result: A string that can round-trip to an identical number.
>
> Supported by: Single, Double, and BigInteger.
>
> Precision specifier: Ignored.
>
> More information: [The Round-trip ("R") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString).

```
String.Format("{0:R} some text...", value)
```

will give you

```
52.30298270000003 some text...
```

Comment: Ah, I need more practice on stackoverflow, you guys are fast :) ! Good stuff, mate.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var value = 52.30298270000003;

var str = string.Format("{0} some text...", value.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(str); // output: 52.3029827
```

The MSDN documnetation has the following to say about the `ToString` method of Singles and Doubles and using `ToString("R")`:

> By default, the return value only contains 7 digits of precision
>   although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally. If the value
>   of this instance has greater than 7 digits, ToString(String) returns
>   PositiveInfinitySymbol or NegativeInfinitySymbol instead of the
>   expected number. If you require more precision, specify format with
>   the "G9" format specification, which always returns 9 digits of
>   precision, or "R", which returns 7 digits if the number can be
>   represented with that precision or 9 digits if the number can only be
>   represented with maximum precision.

Comment: How can a double be a single?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "a double is basically a single"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant float and single, and then changed it to double :|  Edited answer to not be so confusing.